# [__NSCFType set]: unrecognized selector with NSAttributedString:draw() gets called, based on width of position

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, uigraphicsimagerenderer

If the code below is run it causes an exception

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType set]: unrecognized
> selector sent to instance 0x283130be0'

However, the exception can be removed by reducing the width value from 100.0 in `positionRect`, for example setting it to something like 50.0 removes the exception.

But why is this? With a width value of 100.0 specified for `positionRect`, that's well short of the width of `imageSize`. And even if there is some size issue, why is there an unrecognized selector exception?

```
let imageSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 100)
let testRenderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageSize)
let testImage = testRenderer.image { context in
    context.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
    context.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imageSize))
    
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8.0),
        .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.white.cgColor
    ]
    
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "This is some text", attributes: attributes)
    let positionRect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100.0, height: 8.0)
    attributedString.draw(with: positionRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
}
```

Comment: Try changing `.foregroundColor: UIColor.white.cgColor` to `.foregroundColor: UIColor.white`. The color needs to be a UIColor, not a CGColor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to passing a `CGColor` instead of a `UIColor` for the `.foregroundColor` key in your `attributes` dictionary. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1533563-foregroundcolor) states:

> In macOS, the value of this attribute is an NSColor instance. In iOS, tvOS, watchOS, and Mac Catalyst, the value of this attribute is a UIColor instance. Use this attribute to specify the color of the text during rendering. If you don’t specify this attribute, the text renders in black.

The `NSAttributedString` code is attempting to call `set` on the provided color as indicated by the error. This is indicated in the error message showing the Objective-C syntax `-[__NSCFType set]`. This shows that `set` is being called on an object of type `__NSCFType` which is an internal type representing many Core Foundation (and Core Graphics) types, such as `CGColor`.

In short, change the line:

```
.foregroundColor: UIColor.white.cgColor
```

to:

```
.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
```